# Expanding/Collapsing items in GridView

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

My javascript is able to work fine on anypage. I want to use the same code for expanding/collapsing item fields in an ASP.NET GridView. The following code works only for the first item, but not for the rest. Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var setupModule = function () {
            $('#panels-demo').dnnPanels();
            $('#panels-demo .dnnFormExpandContent a').dnnExpandAll({
                targetArea: "panels-demo"
            });
        };
        setupModule();
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () {
            // note that this will fire when _any_ UpdatePanel is triggered,
            // which may or may not cause an issue
            setupModule();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Aspx page:

```
<ItemTemplate>
                <div class="dnnForm" id="panels-demo">
                    <div class="dnnFormExpandContent"><a href="#">Expand All</a></div>
                    <h2 id="tabPassport" class="dnnFormSectionHead"><a href='<%# "#" & Eval("ApplicationID") %>'>Options</a></h2>
                    <fieldset class="dnnClear">
                        <img src="<%=ResolveUrl("/images/passport.jpg") %>" alt="Passport upload" class="dnnLeft" style="width: 10px; height: 10px" />
                        <div class="dnnRight" style="width: 90%; margin-left: 2%">

                            <label>Email user</label>

                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="StatusLabel"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: @Pavlo Yes, no luck..

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the page to collapse all items (edit 'div[id ^= "panels-demo' with your own jquery selectors!!!):

```
<pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        //collapse panels
        $('div[id ^= "panels-demo"] a').removeClass('dnnSectionExpanded');        
        $('fieldset.dnnClear').hide();
    });
</script> 
</pre>
```

Add this to expand all items:

```
<pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        //expand paneles
        $('div[id ^= "panels-demo"] a').addClass('dnnSectionExpanded');
        $('fieldset.dnnClear').show();
    });
</script>
</pre>
```